# How do I use an element's attribute when performing an animation on it in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

If I have a load of elements, that may look like:

```
<p class="test" data-left="250" data-bottom="55">Good morning.</p>
<p class="test" data-left="350" data-bottom="123">Good afternoon.</p>
<p class="test" data-left="290" data-bottom="300">Good night.</p>
```

...and so on, how can I animate them? I initially tried:

```
$('.test').animate({
  left: $(this).attr('data-left'),
  bottom: $(this).attr('data-bottom')
});
```

but it seems the `$(this)` context isn't available right here. Is there a way to do this? Or would it just be a case of writing an `.each()` loop to implement it?

**Note:** We are using an older version of jQuery, hence the use of `.attr()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over those elements:

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({
        left: +$this.attr('data-left'),
        bottom: +$this.attr('data-bottom')
    });
});
```

I think you might have to parse the unitless strings into numbers as well.

Comment: works without parsing the strings but yup, thanks a lot. Seems like it could be a handy to have $(this) available right there! Ah well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.each()`

```
$('.test').each(function(){
   $(this).animate({
            left:$(this).attr('data-left'),
            bottom:$(this).attr('data-bottom')
   })
});
```